# KSH: diference between -eq and =

Tags: ksh

Let say I have this small program:

```
until [ "$name" = "$secretname" ]
do
read name
done
```

Instead of using =, if i used -eq it still works.

Is there a reason for using the "=" over the "-eq"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-eq` is only for comparing integers. It will ignore leading zeroes:

```
$ test 09 -eq 9 && echo match || echo no match
match
```

It will also report an error if the arguments are not integers:

```
$ test abc -eq abc && echo match || echo no match
bash: test: abc: integer expression expected
no match
```

`=` is for comparing arbitrary strings

```
$ test abc = abc && echo match || echo no match
match

$ test 09 = 9 && echo match || echo no match
no match
```

Answer (score 1):

According to `TEST(1)` on my Ubuntu Linux,

```
STRING1 = STRING2
          the strings are equal

INTEGER1 -eq INTEGER2
          INTEGER1 is equal to INTEGER2
```

So, use `=` for string comparison and `-eq` for integer comparison.  Integer comparison **sounds** more efficient to me, so I would suggest you use it if you are actually comparing integers.  Otherwise I suspect you are going to be parsing/hashing your strings to integers or something weird like that.  However, to know for sure, testing would be required.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
-eq is for numbers
= is for strings
```

[Documentation](http://www.well.ox.ac.uk/~johnb/comp/unix/ksh.html#comparisons)